# CMD Process Sometimes Printing Arbitrary Output When Closing Command Line

Tags: java, process, cmd, java.util.scanner

The basis of the code is that a Windows CMD terminal will be opened. When closed, sometimes an extra output is printed. Why is this extra line (`Output: U:\Java\Type Test>`) being printed only sometimes?

Here is the code snippet:

```
Process proc = null;
String[] cmd = {"cmd", "/k", "start"};
proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

Scanner in = new Scanner(proc.getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A");
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
OutputStream os = proc.getOutputStream();
InputStream inputStream = proc.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

System.out.println("First:" + proc.isAlive());
String line, foo;
while (proc.isAlive() && in.hasNext()){
    System.out.println("Output: " + in.nextLine());
    proc.destroyForcibly();
}
```

Usual output:

```
First:true
Output:
```

Unusual Output:

```
First:true
Output: 
Output: U:\Java\Type Test>
```

Comment: It just looks as the prompt is part of the process output... Isn't there an option to `cmd` which skips displaying the prompt at all?

Comment: @fge The U:\Java\Type Test> is the prompt, but my question is why would it only print the prompt sometimes?

Comment: Since your first command to open a command prompt `cmd` is also run from the command prompt that java detects using environments. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`